# HeatMap Result for Survey Questions

Tags: java, javascript, heatmap

I am developing a web application this application is purely based on survey. Each Section has some set of questions, I will expose those questions to user and user have to answer. After answering I will evaluate answers and provide their results in HeatMap. 
For example I have an web page. In that web page questions will be in different sections.
Section-A to E has ten questions and for every correct answer i will have some marks. I have to consolidate total marks in each section and display those result in HeatMAP

Can I know where to start ?? or any examples ?

It may be helpful ? thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by HeatMap?? Is it HashMap?

Comment: Probably you need to read something about basic application development in Java. And then ask specific questions! :)

Comment: Heat map is graphical representation of data.

Comment: Its not hash map its heat Map only